# Why does ruby's IO readlines method behave differently when followed by a filter

Tags: ruby, io

I'm building a little Wordle inspired project for fun and am gathering the words from my local dictionary. Originally I was doing this:

```rb
word_list = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words", chomp: true)
word_list.filter { |word| word.length == 5 }.map(&:upcase)
```

The first line takes absolutely ages. However when doing this:

```rb
word_list = File.readlines("/usr/share/dict/words", chomp: true).filter { |word| word.length == 5 }.map(&:upcase)
```

it completes in a matter of seconds. I can't work out how the `filter` block is being applied to the lines being read before they're assigned memory (which I'm assuming is what is causing the slow read time), clearly each method isn't being fully applied before the next is called but that is how I thought method chaining works.

Comment: Are you running the 2 lines in console or actually in a ruby file? I have a suspicion that the part taking "ages" is printing out the whole word_list rather than reading it from file.

Comment: @SiimLiiser That's a good point, that may be the bottleneck. I was running the code in IRB to test methods of getting the values, the return value ends with: `, "abaciscus", "abacist"...` (including the '...') so I thought it was ruby being lazy and not displaying everything it doesn't need, but maybe that's just IRB tidying up the output?

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a file.

```
File.write('t', "dog horse\npig porcupine\nowl zebra\n") #=> 34
```

then

```
a = File.readlines("t", chomp:true)
  #=> ["dog horse", "pig porcupine", "owl zebra"]
```

so your block variable `word` holds a string of two words. That's obviously not what you want.

You could use [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-read) to "gulp" the file into a string.

```
s = File.read("t")
  #=> "dog horse\npig porcupine\nowl zebra\n"
```

then

```
a = s.scan(/\w+/)
  #=> ["dog", "horse", "pig", "porcupine", "owl", "zebra"].
```

```
b = a.select { |word| word.size == 5 }
  #=> ["horse", "zebra"]
```

```
c = b.map(&:upcase)
  #=> ["HORSE", "ZEBRA"]
```

We could of course chain these operations:

```
File.read("t").scan(/\w+/).select { |word| word.size == 5 }.map(&:upcase)
  #=> ["HORSE", "ZEBRA"]
```

`scan(/\w+/)` matches each string of word characters (letters, digits and underscores). To match only letters change that to `scan(/[a-zA-Z]+/)`.

---

You could use [IO#readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines), which reads lines into an array, by extracting words for each line, filtering the resulting array to keep ones having 5 characters, and then adding those words, after upcasing, to a previously-defined empty array.

```
File.readlines('t')
    .each_with_object([]) { |line,arr| line.scan(/\w+/) }
    .select { |word| word.size == 5 }
    .map(&:upcase)
    .each { |word| arr << word } #=> ["HORSE", "ZEBRA"]
```

You could add the optional parameter `chomp: true` to `readline`'s arguments, but there is no reason to do so.

---

Better would be to use [IO#foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) which, without a block, returns an enumerator which can be chained, avoiding for the temporary array created by `readlines`.

```
File.foreach('t').with_object([]) do |line,arr|
  line.scan(/\w+/)
      .select { |word| word.size == 5 }
      .map(&:upcase)
      .each { |word| arr << word }
end
  #=> ["HORSE", "ZEBRA"]
```